# How can I change subsets value in theano tensor impeded into loop?

Tags: python, deep-learning, theano

layer_Fmaps of size (1,96,236,236)
sitwches of size (1,96,708,708)

in each 3 by 3 matrix in layer_Fmaps there is only cell having a value 1 which should be replace by the opposite value of sitwches

I can't find a way to solve the problem by assigning a direct value into a certain location using a loop

```
def switchs(layer_Fmaps, step=2, switches):
        for idx in range(96):
            for i in range(0, 708, step):
                for j in range(0, 708, step):
                    val = layer_Fmaps[0][idx][i/2,j/2]
                    switches = T.set_subtensor(switches[0][idx][i:i + step, j:j + step],val)
        return  switches
```

knowing that switchs and layer_Fmaps are tensor4

```
img = np.zeros((1,96,236,236))
sswitchs =  np.zeros((1,96,708,708))

inp = T.tensor4('img')
SW = T.tensor4('SW')

tester = switchs(inp,3,SW)

f = theano.function([inp, SW], tester)    

d = f(img,sswitchs)
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
def switchs(layer_Fmaps, switches, step=2):
     for idx in range(96):     
         for i in range(0, 708, step):
             for j in range(0, 708, step):
                 val = layer_Fmaps[0,idx,i/2,j/2]
                 switches = T.set_subtensor(switches[0, idx, i:i + step, j:j + step],val)
     return  switches
```

And:

```
img = np.zeros((1,96,236,236))
sswitchs =  np.zeros((1,96,708,708))

inp = T.tensor4('img')
SW = T.tensor4('SW')

tester = switchs(inp,SW, 3)

f = theano.function([inp, SW], tester)    

d = f(img,sswitchs)
```

I modified several things:

- Replaced 96 for 69. I guess the "96" was a typo.
- Uniform indexing
- Key arguments should be at the end.

Comment: So now you propose that you fixed the problem. it is 96 feature maps and not 69 and there is no typo in making channels decision. chaning the indexing didn't fix anything. also key argument made this way because it is part of a full function not shown here. Did you test your code before your answer ? did understand the problem clearly ?

Comment: If your purpose is to acces the 96th element of a 69 element vector, then NO, I don't understand the problem clearly.

Comment: But maybe I don't understand it because it is poorly redacted and you don't even mention what kind of error you are getting.
If the code is right and the length is 96, then the typo is in the first sentence of your post. Did you read it before posting?

I'll ignore the hostility in your questions and say that, yes. I tested the code above (with smaller numbers, because there is a limit in the time I can waste in your problem) and it runs. I need to make the 3 changes to make the code run.